# Filling Array with user input and using if statements to do arithmetic depending on the value inside array

Tags: java

Here's the question:

Write a Java program that reads in a series of positive integer and writes out the product of all the integers less than 25 and the sum of all the integers greater than or equal to 25. Use 0 as a sentinel value.

I was able to understand how to let the user add the input to an array. But I could not find a way to integrate the code with if statements to make a full working program to do the task. Here's my findings as of now;

```
import java.util.*;
public class UserInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
            System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
            if (stdin.next().startsWith("y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter : ");
                list.add(stdin.next());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        System.out.println("List is " + list);
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

How is it possible to make the array read the input and find the product of all numbers under 25 and the sum of all the numbers above 25. Between, what is sentinel value and how useful is it to know?

**Solution:**
After hours of tweaking the answers posted by volunteers below, I was able to find a solution which worked for me. I hereby posted it in case anyone finds it useful;

```
import java.util.*;
  public class UserInput {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    System.out.println("Current list is : " + list);
    System.out.println("Enter number : ");
    int  entered = stdin.nextInt();
    if(entered == 0){
        int sum = 0,product = 1;
        for(Integer number : list){
            if(number<25){
                sum += number; 
            }else if(number >= 25){
                product *= number;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
        System.out.println("product : " + product);
    }else{
        list.add(entered);
        int sum = 0,product = 1;
        for(Integer number : list){
            if(number<25){
                sum += number; 
            }else if(number >= 25){
                product *= number;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
        System.out.println("product : " + product);
    }           
    System.out.println("Add more numbers to the list ? (Y/N) : ");

    } while(stdin.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your posts and comments! It was really helpful! :)

Comment: I think a sentinel value means that you enter 0 to signal the program to end

Comment: Yes, lose the y/n bit and let them enter a number to add or 0 to compute the sum and product.

Comment: You can use `stdin.nextInt()` and it will convert it to an `int` for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numsGe25 = new ArrayList<>();  // Store numbers greather than or equal to 25 

        List<Integer> numsLt25 = new ArrayList<>();  // Store numbers less than 25


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = -1;
        // Reads a number from the standard input till the 0 value is inserted. 0 is the sentinel
        while ((num = in.nextInt()) != 0) {  
            if (num >= 25) {
                numsGe25.add(num)   
            } else {
                numsLt25.add(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum of numbers >= 25: " + sum(numsGe25));
        System.out.println("product of numbers < 25: " + product(numsLt25));
    }

    private static int sum(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int result = 0;
        for (Integer num : numbers) {
            result += num;
        }
        return result; 
    }

    private static int product(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int result = 1;
        for (Integer num : numbers) {
            result *= num;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class UserInput {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("Current list is : " + list);
        System.out.println("Enter number : ");
        int  entered = stdin.nextInt();
        if(entered != 0){
            list.add(entered);
        }else{
            int sum = 0,product = 1;
            for(Integer number : list){
                if(number<25){
                    sum += number; 
                }else if(number >= 25){
                    product *= number;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
            System.out.println("product : " + product);
            break;
        }           
        System.out.println("Add more numbers to the list ? (Y/N) : ");
    }while(stdin.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work initially but I was able to tweak your work to find the right answer!